# How determine elapsed time for encrypt and decrypt with CipherOutputStream in java?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, benchmarking

I try determined elapsed time for encrypt and decrypt separately in AES algorithm 
Is my code below true method if no please tell me where is find that?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

import de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider;

public class ExampleCrypt123 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES128_CBC", "FlexiCore");

        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "FlexiCore");
        SecretKey secKey = keyGen.generateKey();

        String cleartextFile = "F:/java_projects/cleartext.txt";
        String ciphertextFile = "F:/java_projects/ciphertextSymm.txt";
        String cleartextAgainFile = "F:/java_projects/cleartextAgainSymm.txt";

        byte[] block = new byte[16];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        // Encrypt
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for(int j=0; j< 1000000; j++){
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
                cos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            cos.close();
        }
        long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        System.out.println("Total execution time to create 1000 objects in Java in millis: "
                + elapsedTime/1000000);

        // Decrypt



        fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextAgainFile);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);

        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        for(int j=0; j< 1000000; j++){
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
            int i;

            while (( i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
                fos.write(block, 0, i);
            }
            fos.close();
        }
        long elapsedTime2 = System.nanoTime() - startTime2;

        System.out.println("Total execution time to create 1000  objects in Java in millis: "
                + elapsedTime2/1000000);
    }
```

When run this program on my laptop give me the following results
Total execution time to create 1000 objects in Java in millis: 1416
Total execution time to create 1000  objects in Java in millis: 1600

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not right. For example you open the `fis` stream only once, so you actually process it only once in your encryption loop.

And you make the same mistake in your decryption loop.

Comment: Thank you Mr   ntoskrnl. I tried measure  Execution time for encrypt process and decrypt process to files has size 1,2, .....and 10 kb. I need those results to compare with them. 
But I not sure where set start and end time System.nanoTime(); to compute execution time for that. I use FlexiCoreProvider in java to implement AES symmetric algorithm. Any suggest to solve my problem.

Comment: I still wait for answer